# Is this journal a scam: Requires payment, invited to submit via email, no comments from reviewers, journal not listed on scimagojr rankings

Tags: journals, publishers, disreputable-publishers

After having presented a paper of mine at a conference last summer, I received an email from someone claiming to be part of an editorial team of a journal, to whom my paper was recommended. I sent my work to them, and received an unconditional acceptance after four weeks. But there have been some things that made me doubtful on whether it is actually a good idea to go on and publish there.

I received no comments from reviewers. The journal claims on the website that it is "peer-reviewed" (says nothing on the blindness). When I inquired about comments, the assistant to the editor told me that the editor's comments could be forwarded to me, but that that would take some time. I am currently waiting for this (for about three weeks).

The contact I have with them, exclusively with the editor's assistant, has been interesting. I receive emails at times when people in the US (it is an American journal) are unlikely to work. The person has an Indian-sounding name, and the hours of activity are more likely to be Indian working hours than American.

I could not find anything on the assistant to the editor online. She has referred to me multiple times as "Dr.", even though I am not yet, never used that prefix, and wrote to her after the first time that that is the wrong title. In general, the mails are unresponsive, and only answer one question out of three I asked them, etc.

On the journal website, they cite their h-index for the year 2010, and compare it to those of other journals in 2010. The journal does not appear in the ranking at https://www.scimagojr.com/journalsearch.php?q=JOURNAL+NAME. In turn, I do not know how reputable that website is, but it looks quite complete.

I can not find a list of articles that appeared in this journal on their website. I would like such a list to compare my article to others, and to see who the other authors are, how often their articles were subsequently cited, etc. As the journal's name is consisting of quite generic words, it is difficult to find articles from it on Google scholar - or they are not even indexed on Google scholar, although they claim to be on their website.

I also sent emails to academics that are listed on the Journals website as editors. They were not listed with institutional affiliations, but I googled their names, found academics with the same name and active in overall the same academic field, and wrote them emails, asking about their affiliation with the journal and whether it is legit. I received no replies.

In case of acceptance, I have to pay 320$ to publish, this includes the subscription to the journal for one year.

I am now wondering whether, given all of the above, it is a good journal to publish in, or whether there even is such a thing as a scam in this area of academia that I need to be aware of. Other journals also require a publication fee or even a submission fee, but in their cases, it is more clear to the authors what they gain in return. If it is not a financial scam, could it be a sort of academic scam - an attempt to steal results? But what good are stolen results with no data?

**Should I mention the publisher and the journal name in this question?**

Comment: All the information you've provided supports the hypothesis that the journal is a scam. Do you have any information that might make the journal look honest?

Comment: Honestly, no. I went through the list of editors, and those I searched for seem to exist, but are not at a position in their career where being the editor of a journal seems plausible.

Comment: I'd maybe submit your last-line question in Meta, but I can't see why it would be a problem to give it as an example and then ask more generally how to identify predatory/scam journals. Two points, though: not every major journal is edited in the US, and in my experience delays in review/acceptance probably increase the chance you have legit journal. I agree though that with everything else it doesn't look good.

Comment: "*I received an email from someone claiming to be part of an editorial team of a journal*" 99% of what you need to detect if it is a scam, in your first line.

Comment: I receive about 15 of these a week. Generally, a journal will NEVER need to look for research (unless you are really really successful). See: https://beallslist.weebly.com/

Comment: Three weeks ago, I told the journal I'd accept if they send me the feedback, on which I am still waiting. Does that mean that the research is burnt? Should I, or do I even have to, mention this when submitting the work elsewhere, even if I am sure now that it is not a journal (in the narrow sense)?

Comment: @Marie.P. I'm unsure. Do you have legal advisers at your university?

Comment: no, unfortunately not!

Comment: "Generally, a journal will NEVER need to look for research" the exception for this is a brand new journal that has just opened for submissions in the last few months.

Comment: According to the given details (low apc-price, low reputation, Indian-accent) the correct term isn't predatory journal but BRICS journal. Brics is an acronym for Brazil, Russia, India and China. Are you interested in an economic area which includes 3 billion people?

Comment: @ManuelRodriguez ...except that they're pretending to be an American journal, and apparently lying about their peer review process, and possibly about their h-index. That sounds less like a *bona fide* BRICS journal and more like 'predatory'.

Comment: I disagree with the comment that a journal will never solicit content.  For instance, someone might edit a special issue of papers on a particular topic, and find that the number of submissions is below expectations.  They might find papers that would fit the issue and invite submissions. I've done this as an editor of an IEEE magazine, which is still archival and well respected.  For me, the red flag is requiring a subscription to submit to the journal. Sounds like a pyramid scheme!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Definitely a scam. I get these invitations every couple of months, from an organisation whose acronym quite appropriately rhymes with "diarrhea".

> After having presented a paper of mine at a conference last summer,

I will guess that this conference published a list of presenters online, and that this list included your email address and your topic...

> I received an email from someone claiming to be part of an editorial team of a journal, to whom my paper was recommended.

If it's legit, I would expect them to mention *who* recommended your work. But unless you've produced something world-shattering, it's *very* unlikely that a legitimate journal would be cold-calling you to invite you to submit.

> I sent my work to them, and received an unconditional acceptance after four weeks... I received no comments from reviewers

Yeah, the quick turn-around plus lack of comments is a pretty good sign that their "peer review" is non-existent. I've never known a peer reviewer who couldn't find *something* to say, even if it was just "you should cite these eight papers by the very eminent Prof. P.R. Revua".

> The contact I have with them, exclusively with the editor's assistant, has been interesting. I receive emails at times when people in the US (it is an American journal) are unlikely to work. The person has an Indian-sounding name, and the hours of activity are more likely to be Indian working hours than American.

An Indian-sounding name doesn't mean anything on its own; there are plenty of eminent academics of Indian origin all over the world. But the rest of this is definitely suspicious.

The ones who spam me also have a poor grasp of English grammar; while that's not unusual for academics (even the native English speakers, cough cough), it's very suspicious for a publisher. The fact that you can't find information about other articles they've published is also a strong sign of a scam.

It's very unlikely that these people are trying to steal your results. More likely, they're just trying to get a $320 fee out of you for significantly less than $320 worth of work on their part. They may publish your work but it's not going to be worth anything to you, and may even count against you if you list this journal on your CV. It's also quite possible that if you *do* pay the $320, they'll hit you up for more.

Your advisor should be able to give you some advice on more reputable journals in your field. In the meantime, keep your money, and be on the lookout for more scam attempts - once a scammer gets a response from somebody, they're very likely to target that person for future scams, or sell them on to another scammer.

Edited 8/6 in response to further information with examples of the reviews:

I don't think informal tone or minor spelling/grammar issues from a reviewer are suspicious in themselves. Reviews don't have to be as formal as a published article, and many reviewers aren't perfect English speakers.

What I do notice is that the writing style is quite similar between these two reviews. I can't be sure from the few paragraphs provided, but I wouldn't be terribly surprised if they were both written by the same person.

One error that *did* raise my eyebrow was Reviewer 1's repeated "et. Al" which should be "*et al.*, short for Latin "et alia". This is such a common part of academic English that I'm surprised any serious academic wouldn't know it.

More suspicious IMHO is the point that @NajibIdrissi noted: these reviews are very generic. Without any previous experience in your field, I daresay I could write something like this after five minutes of skimming your paper and five more of googling for references that match your keywords, and I could recycle 90% of it for the next review I needed to produce.

There are always more papers that *could* be included in the lit review, there's always more room to discuss further applications, and every author wants to be told that their model is valid and their methods are sound.

Comment: While agreeing 99% with your analysis, I suspect "_et. Al_" is _probably_ simply Word (or similar) auto-capitalising after a full stop.

Comment: @TripeHound I agree that auto-capitalisation is probably involved, but there shouldn't *be* a full stop at the end of "et". (And there should be one after "al".)

Comment: You're right. I was looking at the "A" so much I didn't notice that the "." that caused it was wrong as well! Make that 100% agree, then.

Comment: @TripeHound in fact MS Word knows that "et al." is correct and *does not* attempt to "correct" it to something else...

Comment: @silvado As I said, I'd failed to spot the "." after "et" was wrong (I _knew_ it was, but had overlooked it when commenting). Typing "`e` `t` `.` `spc` `a` _did_ trigger a "correction", but it was the wrong test.

Answer (score 12):

The information you provide points toward a predatory journal, here to take your money with little benefits for you. **Do not pay the publishing fees**.

In the future, here is a few things you could verify before sending a manuscript to an unknown journal (not an exhaustive list):

1. On their website, can you see an editorial board with clear affiliations? If yes, try to verify if the editors listed are really members of these organism. Many universities have a list of faculty member.
2. Look at the published articles of the journal. Can you find them in your usual search engine or even in the search engine the journal boast they are in?
3. As a general check, how does the website looks? Is is boasting an impact factor on the homepage? Does it have detailed information about the peer review process?

If the journal is Open Access, you could verify if it is listed in [DOAJ](https://doaj.org/). I am a DOAJ editor and we do verify the legitimacy of journals. If you do not like DOAJ (I know some people here don't), there exist list of predatory journals you could verify.

Comment: @Marie.P. Note the link is to a list of *not* predatory journals

Comment: **4. Have you ever cited, or even read, a paper published in the journal?**  (A negative answer doesn't necessarily mean the journal is a scam, but it does suggest either that the journal is a poor match for your research, or that you haven't done an adequate literature search.)

Comment: This is a good point. No, I have not, and I could not even find articles online that were published in that journal  and were unrelated to my research.

Comment: The addition by @JeffE is a good point

Answer (score 1):

As the suggestions have been very clear, I have withdrawn my submission, while not being encouraged to name the journal or publisher here. Instead, you said I should focus on describing their practices to keep the question general.

As such, what now happened is that, after having waited a few weeks for revierw's comments, and hearing nothing, I wrote the assistant to the editor that I would withdraw my submission. Immediately, they sent the following document.

I marked those phrases that put me off in particular, because they were sloppy, too general, or should have been substantiated more. These reviews seem like a hastily compiled document by someone with no academic backgroup, who tries to appear academic.

In the first review, the word "his" might just be a typo from "this", but it just adds further questions on the blindness of the review process.
The second paper they refer to, I could not find. The first, I could find, but at first glance it does not look too relevant. However, I will look at it in more detail. The argument that "as any author knows, at some point you have to limit what is included" seems, however, closer to student's wishful thinking than to appropriate rigor.

[image]

---

The second reviewer states that the previously employed methods are subjective and highly questionable, but that they are impressed with my methods. However, my methods are just combinations and extensions of previous methods. I can also not understand why they would *like* changes to be made, but not *require* them to be made.

[image]

Comment: To be honest the reviews don't seem very different from the ones I've seen. Reviewers certainly can write in informal language. Typos in reviews aren't uncommon either. It shouldn't be the case either that they were written by people with non-academic backgrounds: the intellectual level is way too high (you could try writing a review in a field you are unfamiliar with for example), and the first reviewer even linked two related studies. If anything I'd guess the first reviewer was an editorial board member since it referred to "our journal"; ordinary reviewers do not do that.

Comment: Having said that, I'm not criticizing your decision to withdraw - it's up to you.

Comment: These "reviewers comments" are so generic that they could be about almost any scientific paper ever written.

Comment: I would suggest that you edit this information into your original question. I have some comments to make on it, but I'll do that as part of my own answer.

Comment: @Allure from OP's remarks, one of the two "related studies" could be found, and the other doesn't appear to be relevant to her paper. That doesn't seem like much evidence of anything more than googling on keywords.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent perhaps but regardless, it's still something that takes expertise to do. At what level do you expect a student to be able to conduct literature reviews? I'd say at least Bachelor (Hons) level, preferably Masters. I'll say as well I cannot imagine most of my former colleagues in academic publishing writing these reviews from scratch, especially of this length in less than a day. Most would not even know how to start, and they have BS degrees.

Comment: @Allure What is even your point here? That the fake journal's "staff" has at least one person with a master's degree? Probably the fake reviewer went on google scholar, searched for "related papers", and included a random one that was not in OP's bibliography, and another that does not even exist. This takes no skill. But in any case, this is not how serious reviews look like, end of story...

Comment: @Allure From what the OP wrote, it's not at all clear that these reviewers *did* conduct any serious literature review. Nor do we know that these reviews *were* written from scratch for the OP's paper; for all I can see, most of the content could've been recycled with minimal changes from some other review.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent they could, yeah. But they could also have been written by real reviewers. I would not leap to conclusions; as I wrote, these reviews would not be out of place compared to other reviews I've seen; they aren't even terrible reviews and I can think of worse ones written be genuine faculty in major North American universities (so bad they've etched themselves into my memory). To conclude the journal is shady based only on these reviews is, I think, premature.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent based on the OP's description, I actually think most of it should not trigger alarm bells. The assistant-to-the-editor using Dr. for example is natural, since one naturally assumes that everyone in academia holds a PhD. To be instructed not to use Dr. and still use Dr. - that's a sign that the assistant is not very well-trained or diligent, but that applies to a lot of people I know in genuine publishers (don't overestimate how diligent people are).

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent I'd say the biggest warning signs are: 1) no articles on journal's website which is inexcusable, 2) generic journal title to the point it is not Googleable, and 3) pay-to-publish *and* subscription at the same time; subscription journals shouldn't charge APCs. The others are potentially troubling, but also potentially ordinary, and I wouldn't draw conclusions.

Comment: @Allure I don't think anybody *was* drawing conclusions based only on those reviews? I certainly wasn't. As well as the other factors you mention, the nature of the approach, swift turn-around, and reluctance to provide those reviews all seem shady to me. But the rest is supporting evidence; not much on its own, but part of a broader pattern.

Comment: @Allure I'm also genuinely surprised to hear that this level of feedback would be typical for a legit review. Granted my sample size is relatively small, and there may be disciplinary differences, but every PR I've ever received or given has been much more specific and detailed than these.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent It might not be "typical", but it certainly happens. I'm just as surprised you have not encountered this kind of review before. Perhaps you could ask your colleagues what the worst reviewer report they've received looks like? See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogdanov_affair#Reflections_upon_the_peer-review_system